# Max and Distinct SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

```
set search_path = 'project';

select g.firstname,g.lastname, g.rating, sh.showname
from guest g, shows sh, timeslot ts
where sh.shownumber = ts.shownumber
and ts.guestnumber = g.guestnumber 
order by sh.showname
```

this is the result

```
"Charlie ";"Sheen";7.2;"Cooking Show"
"Charlie";"Sheen";7.2;"Cooking Show"
"Carl";"Makky";7.0;"Cooking Show"
"Barack";"Obama";6.7;"Fitness Mania"
"Vladimir";"Putin";8.2;"Fitness Mania"
"kim";"jung";5.3;"Fitness Mania"
"kim";"jung";5.3;"Gamers Heaven"
"Justin";"Trudeau";8.5;"Kids Play Time"
"Charlie";"Sheen";7.2;"Kids Play Time"
"ellen";"page";9.2;"Weather News"
```

What I want is the highest rated guest PER SHOW, so it should have 5 records, one record of each available show with the highest rating guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one guest per show - you can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on (sh.showname) g.firstname, g.lastname, g.rating, sh.showname
from guest g, shows sh, timeslot ts
where sh.shownumber = ts.shownumber
and ts.guestnumber = g.guestnumber 
order by sh.showname, g.rating desc
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good application of the `row_number()` function:

```
select firstname, lastname, rating, showname
from (select g.firstname, g.lastname, g.rating, sh.showname,
             row_number() over (partition by sh.showname order by g.rating desc) as seqnum
      from guest g shows sh join
           timeslot ts
           on sh.shownumber = ts.shownumber join
           guest g
           on ts.guestnumber = g.guestnumber  
     ) gr
where seqnum = 1
order by showname;
```

I also modified the code to use explicit `join` syntax.

If you want five guests per show, use `seqnum <= 5`.

Comment: I want one highest rated guest per show, it means 5 records as in one guest per show, its 5 records because I have a database of 5 shows

Comment: @user3241846 . . . Okay, that is what the query does with `seqnum = 1`.

Comment: I like this.  I've found this task -- wanting the best entire row for some criterion -- to be an awkward corner case in SQL, which I've previously handled with hacks like `SELECT ... FROM tbl t1 WHERE ... AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.X = t1.X and t2.criterion < t1.criterion)`, but this doesn't easily let you get the best k rows.  Your way is more general, and saves a JOIN!